# Deluxetable: Class memoir Error: Illegal pream-token (\string): `c' used

Tags: tables, memoir, aastex, deluxetable

I am using the [deluxetable](https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/standard30/deluxetable.sty) package within a document using a custom thesis class file built on Memoir. The following error keeps being thrown:

> Class memoir Error: Illegal pream-token (\string): `c' used. See the
>   memoir class documentation for explanation.
>
> l.179 \startdata

The error is always caused by the `\startdata` line of the deluxetable. Replacing or changing the case of the alignment arguments (i.e. from 'C' to 'c', or replacing all 'c' alignment arguments with 'r' for example) *does not solve the problem*.

Here is an MNWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{deluxetable}
\begin{document}
\begin{deluxetable}{lrlll}
  %\tabletypesize{\footnotesize}
  %\rotate
  \tablewidth{0pc}
  \tablecaption{ Parameters \label{table:params}}
  \tablehead{
    \colhead{Parameter} & \colhead{Symbol} & \colhead{Value} & \colhead{1-    $\sigma$ Error} & \colhead{Units}}
  \startdata
  Observable x & $x$ & 0.21 & $\pm$ 0.04\footnote{Some footnote} & \\
  \\
  \\
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{\emph{Some other parameters}} \\
  \\
  Observable y & $y$ & 5.7 & $\pm$ 0.08 & units
  \enddata
  \tablecomments{Table comments here.}
\end{deluxetable}
\end{document}
```

I'll note the table does compile, but the error still must be fixed.

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, we cannot use your code to reproduce the error as it stands. Can you reproduce with a standard class? If not, provide a link to the class.

Comment: Also, a link to `deluxetable.sty` which doesn't seem to be on CTAN.

Comment: I have linked to deluxetable and now provide a link to the class file.

Comment: https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/standard30/deluxetable.sty

Comment: The class file you've linked to is unusable. Please provide a link to a usable version which includes all required backslashes.

Comment: I've edited your question to provide a significantly more minimal example. While this still needs `deluxetable.sty`, it does not need the custom class. If you do not agree that this produces the same problem, feel free to roll back my edit. However, I get the same error you report. (I can't test with the class as I don't have a usable version.) It will be easier for people to help with this code.

Answer (score 4):

> ***I very strongly recommend* NOT *combining `deluxetable` with Memoir.***
>
> ## *Caveat emptor ...*

The problem is that `deluxetable` stores the tabular specification in a macro prefixed by `\string`. Somehow, Memoir affects the way in which this macro is later expanded or treated.

## Recommended Solution

Forget `deluxetable`. Use standard packages which work with Memoir instead. For example,

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Parameters \label{table:params}}
    \begin{tabular}{lrlll}
      \toprule
      Parameter & Symbol & Value & 1- $\sigma$ Error & Units\\
      \midrule
      Observable x & $x$ & 0.21 & $\pm$ 0.04\tnotex{tn:footnote} & \\
      \\
      \\
      \multicolumn{5}{c}{\emph{Some other parameters}} \\
      \\
      Observable y & $y$ & 5.7 & $\pm$ 0.08 & units\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item[a]\label{tn:footnote} Some footnote
      \note{Table comments here.}
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: recommended solution]

## Dis-recommended Hack

**IF** you only need **simple** tabular specifications e.g. just letters with nothing fancy, then you can eliminate the `\string` and the tabular will be typeset as normal.

Probably.

Possibly.

At least in the case of the code in the example.

I think.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{deluxetable}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{deluxetable}[1]{%
 \def\pt@format{#1}%
 \let\@acol\pt@tabacol
 \let\@tabularcr\@ptabularcr
 \let\@tablenotetext\@ptablenotetext
 \let\@tablenotes\@ptablenotes
 \global\pt@ncol\z@
 \global\pt@column\z@
 \global\pt@page\@ne
 \gdef\pt@addcol{\global\advance\pt@ncol\@ne}%
}{%
 \spew@tblnotes
 \typeout@deluxetable
 \endcenter
 \end@plano@float
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{deluxetable}{lrlll}
  \tablewidth{0pc}
  \tablecaption{ Parameters \label{table:params}}
  \tablehead{
    \colhead{Parameter} & \colhead{Symbol} & \colhead{Value} & \colhead{1-    $\sigma$ Error} & \colhead{Units}}
  \startdata
  Observable x & $x$ & 0.21 & $\pm$ 0.04\footnote{Some footnote} & \\
  \\
  \\
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{\emph{Some other parameters}} \\
  \\
  Observable y & $y$ & 5.7 & $\pm$ 0.08 & units
  \enddata
  \tablecomments{Table comments here.}
\end{deluxetable}
\end{document}
```

[image: possibly typeset table, perhaps]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't comment yet, but looks to me as the deluxetable may not be compatible with memoir on which your thesis class seems to be based. I have tested your code on sharelatex and am getting the same error. However if you change your documentclass to \documentclass{article}, the error should go away. Deluxetable is very old, from 1995 and may have a number of problems with newer classes etc.

The example below should work without a problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{deluxetable}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{deluxetable}{lcc}
\centering
\tabletypesize{\footnotesize}
\tablewidth{0pt}
\tablecolumns{3}
\tablecaption{THIS IS A TEST}
\tablehead{\colhead{First col.} & \colhead{Second col.} & \colhead{Third col.}}
\startdata
Some & text & here \\
for & the & sake \\
of & testing & this.
\enddata
\tablecomments{Did it work?}
\label{TESTTABLE}
\end{deluxetable}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Another source btw for the deluxetable.sty and an example that uses it can be found here https://github.com/esheldon/latex/blob/master/des-computing/des-computing.tex

Comment: Might it be better to recommend `book` since this is a thesis and the OP is using `\mainmatter`? I do think that suggesting the OP ditch the class rather than the package is a bit drastic, in any case, especially given that the package is not a standard one. (1995 is not really old in LaTeX terms, especially where tables are concerned.) But if you are going to ditch the class, substituting the equivalent standard class is probably a better option than `article` to write a book.